# PHP DOM Parser for multiple URLs?

Tags: php, web-crawler

I've tried loads of different techniques to load and crawl multiple urls, all of them are not working and I even get apache errors.

Right now I'm trying just to load URLs from file and it's not working, everyhing seems fine to me here, so here's the code:

```
<?php
include_once('simple_html_dom.php');
$target_url = "array.htm";
$html = new simple_html_dom();
$links = $html->load_file($target_url);

foreach ($links as $link)
{
    echo $link;
}

?>
```

Error I get `Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\xampp2\htdocs\copy.php on line 7`

Comment: `wrote this script but its not working.` .. thats not a good description of the problem

Comment: $links and $link. make it `foreach($links as $link)`

Comment: It is now. But not working. Btw I removed now foreach and added `var_dump $html->load_file($target_url);` and I get error `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$html' (T_VARIABLE) in C:\xampp2\htdocs\copy.php on line 9`

Comment: Maybe you forgot a semicolon somewhere?